# Can a QAction accept drops?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I want to develop an application that has a menu with several `QAction` objects in it. I want to drag a file from a `QListView` to one of these `QActions` ? Is it possible ?
Normally they don't accept drops :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, but you can try subclassing and implement a drop/dragenter event. Since QAction is based on QObject i think this won't help. Think about implementing a Widget/Label as MenuItem (Custom Menu) and Drag/Drop there.

Comment: OK thank u . There is something named QWidgetAction that may solve this problem.